# Delete the first line that matches a pattern

Tags: sed

How can I use sed to delete only the first line that contains a certain pattern?

For example, I want to remove the first line matching `FAA` from this document:

```
1. foo bar quuz
2. foo FAA bar (this should go)
3. quuz quuz FAA (this should remain)
4. quuz FAA bar (this should also remain)
```

The result should be

```
1. foo bar quuz
3. quuz quuz FAA (this should remain)
4. quuz FAA bar (this should also remain)
```

A solution for POSIX sed would be greatly appreciated, GNU sed is OK.

Answer (score 8):

With `GNU` sed you can use the following idiom:

```
sed '0,/FAA/{/FAA/d}' input.txt
```

It applies the delete action to a range from the beginning of the file to the first occurrence of `FAA` and removes only that line.

Comment: 0 is not posix compliant (not working on my AIX) but the best action line when available

Comment: @NeronLeVelu `GNU sed is OK`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Thanks for the hint. I'll check this later. Need to hurry and go to the dentist... :) thx (et)Kent

Comment: why you used `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: Using 1 instead of 0 does not produce the correct result if `FAA` is present in the first line.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/FAA/{:a;n;p;ba};p' file
```

Print all lines until you encounter `FAA`, then skip that line and print all subsequent lines to the end of the file.

Comment: still very clean and short, like your style

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '1 {/FAA/ d;};1,/FAA/ {/FAA/d;}' YourFile
```

the case of FAA on first line need a special test (or it take 1st occurence and next one)

an alternative

```
sed '/FAA/ !b
   N;s/.*\n//
:end
   N
   $ p
   b end' YourFile
```

Comment: interesting, I saw this answer just after commenting @hek2mgl's answer. sed has 0 addr. could be easier for this problem.

Comment: and I think in the special case, your `1{...}` part, you need somehow do a `next`. otherwise, if the #1 and #2 line both have `FAA`, both lines would be removed.

Comment: @Kent is right, try `printf "1. a FAA\n2. b FAA\n3. cc dd\n" | sed -e '1 {/FAA/ d;};1,/FAA/ {/FAA/d;}'`. Only the 3rd line is shown.

Comment: strange, i try on my aix with a print and an echo and both take 2nd line and not 1st as expected. So on AIX, sed does not enter in second part after line 1 (if /FAA/ occr on 1st line) but other system enter in the loop after line 1. Could you try with --posix (on GNU sed) ?

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` this is simple to do:

```
awk '!f && /FAA/ {f=1;next}1' file
1. foo bar quuz
3. quuz quuz FAA (this should remain)
4. quuz FAA bar (this should also remain)
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed

```
sed '0,/FAA/{//d}' file
```

For detail => info sed

Comment: Interestingly `sed '1,/.../{//d}' file` produces an error! I also believe this only to apply to GNU sed.